# The given value is not suitable for child module

Tags: terraform

I am trying to set default values on my `map(objects)` variable in terraform but I am getting the following error when using my module:

```
The given value is not suitable for child module variable "virtual_servers"
│ defined at .terraform/modules/{module_name}/variables.tf:122,1-27: element
│ "{element_name}": attributes "client_profiles", "irules", "profiles",
│ "rev_zone", "server_profiles", and "source_address_translation" are
│ required.
```

My understanding is that I should be able to provide sensible defaults in my module and then override those defaults when calling the module.

Here is the code:

*Module*

variables.tf:

```
variable "virtual_servers" {
  type = map(object({
    port                       = number
    fwd_zone                   = string
    rev_zone                   = string
    source_address_translation = string
    irules                     = list(string)
    profiles                   = list(string)
    client_profiles            = list(string)
    server_profiles            = list(string)
  }))
  default = {
    default = {
      port                       = 1
      fwd_zone                   = "test"
      rev_zone                   = "test"
      source_address_translation = "test"
      irules                     = null
      profiles                   = null
      client_profiles            = null
      server_profiles            = null
    }
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "virtual_server" "this" {
  for_each                   = var.virtual_servers
  port                       = each.value.port
  source_address_translation = each.value.source_address_translation
  irules                     = each.value.irules

  profiles        = each.value.profiles
  client_profiles = each.value.client_profiles
  server_profiles = each.value.server_profiles
}
```

*Making use of the module*

main.tf

```
module "module_name" {
source = "module_source"

  virtual_servers_1 = {
    "name" = {
      port                       = 80
      fwd_zone                   = "override"
    }
    "virtual_servers_2" = {
      port                       = 80
      fwd_zone                   = "override"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I am going wrong?

EDIT:
If I pass in all the values required to virtual_servers_1 and virtual_servers_2 it works. However I want to be able to supply default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default` argument inside a `variable` block is only for situations where the caller doesn't set the variable at all. Setting a `default` tells Terraform that the overall argument should be optional and to use the given value instead if it isn't set.

There is no corresponding feature for individual attributes. If you define an attribute as part of an object type then it must always be present in the argument in order for the value to match the type, but the caller *can* set the attribute to `null` explicitly in order to include it in the type without providing a value for it:

```
module "module_name" {
  source = "module_source"

  virtual_servers_1 = {
    "name" = {
      port                       = 80
      fwd_zone                   = "override"
      source_address_translation = null
      irules                     = null
      profiles                   = null
      client_profiles            = null
      server_profiles            = null
    }
    "virtual_servers_2" = {
      port                       = 80
      fwd_zone                   = "override"
      source_address_translation = null
      irules                     = null
      profiles                   = null
      client_profiles            = null
      server_profiles            = null
    }
  }
}
```

Note that, because as noted above `default` is only for when the variable *isn't set at all*, those `null` values will appear directly in the `var.virtual_servers` value. If you want to replace them with actual default values for use elsewhere in your module then you can derive a new value where those values are replaced by defaults, using [the `coalesce` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/coalesce.html) in a local value:

```
locals {
  virtual_servers_1 = tomap({
    for k, s in var.virtual_servers_1 : k => {
      port                       = coalesce(s.port, 1)
      fwd_zone                   = coalesce(s.fwd_zone, "test")
      rev_zone                   = coalesce(s.rev_zone, "test")
      source_address_translation = coalesce(s.source_address_translation, "test")
      irules                     = coalesce(s.irules, tolist([]))
      profiles                   = coalesce(s.profiles, tolist([]))
      client_profiles            = coalesce(s.client_profiles, tolist([]))
      server_profiles            = coalesce(s.server_profiles, tolist([]))
    }
  })
}
```

You can then use `local.virtual_servers_1` instead of `var.virtual_servers_1` elsewhere in the module to guarantee that you'll never encounter a `null`, and will instead see the default value if the input was `null`. (I set the list ones to default to an empty list because that's typically easier to work with elsewhere than a *null* list.)